# Standard crypto algorithm to cipher a number with password

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I have a bank device that is used to do money transfers among accounts. I'm curious about trying to figure out what algorithm is used to cipher the input. It follows the next conditions

-The text that needs to be cipher consists of only 8 digits (e.g. 00000000, 00000001, 99999999, etc)

-It uses some key/password to cipher this input

-The key/pass is a string of n characters

-The output should be of the same length (8 digits)

Is there any standard crypto algos for this?

Comment: This is not a programming question but rather one of cryptanalytic diagnosis, and is too broad to recommend migration to [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is so-called Format-preserving encryption. And yes, it's standartized.
https://doi.org/10.6028%2FNIST.SP.800-38G

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption

Comment: Please ask the question which is not related to opinions, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Right..But vulnerability was reported on NIST FF3 though